# Better way to calculate time between two datetimes in Google Sheets?

Tags: time, google-sheets-formula

I wrote a formula that calculates the time difference between two datetime cells in Google Sheets.

Here is the formula for the time difference in minutes.

```
=(HOUR(B2)-HOUR(A2)+DAYS(B2,A2)*24)*60 + MINUTE(B2)-MINUTE(A2)
```

where `A2` is the start datetime, and `B2` is the end datetime.

[image: start end times]

I feel like Google Sheets should have a simpler method of calculating time differences, but I can't find out what function to use. Does google sheets convert to and from unix timestamps, for example? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In hours

```
=24*(B2-A2)
```

in minutes

```
=24*60*(B2-A2)
```

Comment: I tried to do this earlier but for some reason (can't imagine what) it did not work. Now it works. This is the simplest method of calculating the difference between datetimes.

Answer (score 1):

use in row 2:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(ROUND(24*(B2:B-A2:A), 2)))))
```

---

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/(ROUND(1440*(B2:B-A2:A), 2)))))
```

[image]

Comment: This does seem to work, but I don't immediately understand the formula. Not sure if it is simpler that the one I made.

Comment: @NicoWheat INDEX coz you process whole array/range. IFERROR(1/(1/( to remove zeroes for blank rows. ROUND to round it to 2 decimal places and 24 or 1440 times B column - A column to calculate diference