# What is the Google Sheets formula to calculate the working hours for each specific day based on the source of the chat and the given work schedule?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula, date-difference, ticket-system

With the condition:

Source           Parameters       Start Work End Work
Chat            Monday - Friday            8:00 - 21:00
Email           Monday - Friday            9:00 - 18:00
Chat and Email  Saturday and Sunday        9:00 - 14:00

Full holiday (no working) only on public holiday such as January 1, May 1, December 25 as [attached here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h-hY1KJ7lnwLHAwUuvkTfXlUt55zdvn2vwXDDLiIK-U/edit#gid=1427985673)

What is the Google sheets formula to calculate the working hours of timestamp difference between ticket received and ticket responded above (in minutes)?

IF:

- Ticket from CHAT received on Saturday, 12/31/2022 13:00:00
- Ticket from CHAT responded on Monday, 1/2/2023 10:00:00

What is the Google sheets formula to calculate the working hours of timestamp difference between ticket received and ticket responded above (in minutes)?

The expected answer is 180 minutes: I have 60 minutes left on Saturday but still not responded, skip on Sunday because it is public holiday, and used 120 minutes on Mondday to reply it. I already prepared for others scenario as attached in this sheet[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h-hY1KJ7lnwLHAwUuvkTfXlUt55zdvn2vwXDDLiIK-U/edit#gid=434070620)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you recheck\clarify the expected values posted in  Cells_`H7, H11` since `Sat, Sun` are supposed to have altogether different set of working_hours as per the table in `A1:D4`?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to calculate time between two datetimes in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110556/better-way-to-calculate-time-between-two-datetimes-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow you are right, my bad mistake. It was supposed to be 90 and correct, it is 195. Very attention to the details as always.

Comment: Thank you @rockinfreakshow your formula is working well! Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(E7:E,F7:F,G7:G,lambda(source,created,response,if(len(source)*len(created)*len(response)*(response>=created),let(Σ,sequence(days(response,created)+1,1,created,1),
           Λ,ifna(filter(Σ,iserror(xmatch(Σ,tocol(Holidays!A2:A,1))))),s_,xlookup(source,B2:B3,C2:C3),e_,xlookup(source,B2:B3,D2:D3),
           sum(map(Λ,lambda(Δ,let(start_,if(weekday(Δ,2)<6,s_,C4),end_,if(weekday(Δ,2)<6,e_,D4), round(ifs(
                     min(Λ)=max(Λ),  max(min(Λ+end_,response),Λ+start_)-min(max(Λ+start_,created),Λ+end_),
                     min(Λ)=Δ,       ifs((Δ=int(created))*(timevalue(created)<=end_),end_-max(start_,timevalue(created)),Δ<>int(created),end_-start_,1,),
                     max(Λ)=Δ,       ifs((Δ=int(response))*(timevalue(response)>=start_),min(end_,timevalue(response))-start_,Δ<>int(response),end_-start_,1,),
                     1,              end_-start_)
                     *24*60)))))),)))
```

[image]